# rewrite string query rule on iis7

Tags: string, iis-7, web-config, translate

I'm setting up S2Members on a WordPress based website on a server that runs IIS7 and need to change some settings in order to allow download of restricted files to members.

To do that, I need to translate this rule from apache .htaccess into iis7 web.config.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)s2member_file_download\=.+ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)no-gzip\=1
RewriteRule .* - [E=no-gzip:1]
</IfModule>
```

I did some experimenting, but it ends up crashing the site, so I figured it better to ask someone here who actually knows what they're doing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the rule above is trying to disable GZIP compression when provided the query-string no-gzip == 1 or that other member_file_download... criteria.

To achieve that using URL Rewrite in IIS what you need to do is use the same logic in web.config but use it to override/remove the Accept-Encoding Header so that the server does not see the "accept encoding gzip/deflate" that tells it to compress.

So there are two steps to do that is:
First, add a server variable setting in \windows\system32\inetsrv\config\ApplicationHost.config so that the server allows to override the server setting (you can also do that in the UI using the Server Variables link).

```
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <allowedServerVariables>
                <add name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" />
            </allowedServerVariables>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```

Then you want to add the actual rewrite rule in your web.config, something that looks like follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="DisableGZIP">
                    <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(^|\?|&amp;)s2member_file_download\=.+" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(^|\?|&amp;)no-gzip\=1" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="None" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                    </serverVariables>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

this should work, to test it you can pass the query string ?no-gzip=1 to any URL and you should not get them compressed.

Comment: I don't actually own the server, so I will have to write the support and see if they're willing to do some changes, but now at least I know what to ask of them. So thanks a lot for the help! :)

Comment: By the way you could also ask them to only allow that to your site and they can do that by scoping the xml in a <location path="your-site-name"> and that way no one else is affected or granted permission to override that variable if they have concerns. Reality is that should not be a security issue at all.